# Limit nesting ULs in a 'nesting categories' function

Tags: php, nested

I have an array ($nested) like this (this is the print_r() output)

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [module] => 1
            [parent] => 0
            [name] => Audio
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [module] => 1
            [parent] => 5
            [name] => Mixer analogici
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [module] => 1
            [parent] => 4
            [name] => Videoproiettori
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [module] => 1
            [parent] => 2
            [name] => Strutture
        )

    ...

    [19] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [module] => 1
            [parent] => 5
            [name] => Mixer digitali
        )

)
```

And a recursive function to create a nested menu:

```
function nmenu($module, $parent, $array) {
    $has_children = false;
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['module'] == $module) {  
            if ($value['parent'] == $parent) {       
                if ($has_children === false && $parent) {
                    $has_children = true;
                    echo "<ul>\n";
                }
                echo '<li>';
                echo '' . $value['name'] . " \n";
                    nmenu($module, $key, $array);
                echo "</li>\n";
            }
        }
    }
    if ($has_children === true && $parent) echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

That I call like this:

```
<ul>
    <?php nmenu($row_rsNavModules['mod_id'], 0, $nested) ?>
</ul>
```

All is fine, the recursive function works as expected and it creates a series of infinite nested ULs... well, it's the "infinite" that it's too much: I'd like to limit the indentation level (aka the number of indented ULS) to 2, like this:

```
Cat 1
    Subcat 1-1
    Subcat 1-2
    ...
Cat 2
    Subcat 2-1
    Subcat 2-2
    ...
```

And NOT ending up like this:

```
Cat 1
    Subcat 1-1
            Sub-Subcat 1-1-1
                    Sub-Sub-Subcat 1-1-1-1
                    ...
```

Please, how can I edit the previous function to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to have a counter and quit from the function once the counter reaches your  limit. Something like:

```
//counter parameter added
function nmenu($module, $parent, $array, $counter) {
    $has_children = false;
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['module'] == $module) {  
            if ($value['parent'] == $parent) {       
                if ($has_children === false && $parent) {
                    $has_children = true;
                    echo "<ul>\n";
                }
                echo '<li>';
                echo '' . $value['name'] . " \n";

                if($counter<2){  //added 
                    //counter parameter added
                    nmenu($module, $key, $array, $counter+1);
                } //added
                echo "</li>\n";
            }
        }
    }
    if ($has_children === true && $parent) echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

And call it like this:

```
<ul>
    <?php 
       //counter parameter added 
       nmenu($row_rsNavModules['mod_id'], 0, $nested, 1) 
    ?>
</ul>
```